# \uppercase in \newcommand

Tags: macros, strings, capitalization

I tried to use `\uppercase` in `\newcommand`:

```
\newcommand\universidad{My University}
\newcommand\Universidad{\uppercase{\universidad}}
```

When I use it I get this,

> My University

and not, as expected, this

> MY UNIVERSITY

Why?

#### EDIT

I can't use `\MakeUppercase` because I need use latin quote, example: ingeniería. And this latin case has problems with `\MakeUppercase`

Answer (score 40):

With both `latin1` and `utf8` encodings I get correct output from

```
\newcommand{\facultad}{Ingeniería}
\newcommand{\Facultad}{\expandafter\MakeUppercase\expandafter{\facultad}}
\Facultad
```

The problem with your definition is that `\uppercase` acts on the token list `\universidad` and doesn't do nothing, because at that level there's no letter to be uppercased; `\universidad` is expanded only later. With `\expandafter` we perform the expansion before `\MakeUppercase` comes into action.

Just as an exercise, here is a macro `\Capitalize` that takes as argument a control sequence and defines its "uppercase variant"

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Capitalize}[1]{%
  \edef\@tempa{\expandafter\@gobble\string#1}%
  \edef\@tempb{\expandafter\@car\@tempa\@nil}%
  \edef\@tempa{\expandafter\@cdr\@tempa\@nil}%
  \uppercase\expandafter{\expandafter\def\expandafter\@tempb\expandafter{\@tempb}}%
  \@namedef{\@tempb\@tempa}{\expandafter\MakeUppercase\expandafter{#1}}}
\makeatother
```

After this magic code you can say

```
\newcommand\universidad{Universidad de Lugar}
\newcommand{\facultad}{Ingeniería}

\Capitalize{\universidad}
\Capitalize{\facultad}
```

will define also `\Universidad` and `\Facultad` that will print "UNIVERSIDAD DE LUGAR" and "INGENIERÍA".

Note that `\MakeUppercase` does not go along with **hyperref**, so in case you use these commands where this package extracts something for building bookmarks you should give it a safe token list; for example

```
\newcommand{\Facultad}{%
   \texorpdfstring{\expandafter\MakeUppercase\expandafter{\facultad}}%
      {\facultad}}
```

and, in the automatic defining command, change the line

```
\@namedef{\@tempb\@tempa}{\expandafter\MakeUppercase\expandafter{#1}}}
```

into

```
\@namedef{\@tempb\@tempa}{%
  \texorpdfstring{\expandafter\MakeUppercase\expandafter{#1}}{#1}}}
```

---

In case one's using `utf8x`, the definitions must be preceded by `\PrerenderUnicode`:

```
\PrerenderUnicode{Ingeniería}
\newcommand{\facultad}{Ingeniería}
\newcommand{\Facultad}{\expandafter\MakeUppercase\expandafter{\facultad}}
```

The `\Capitalize` macro could be

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Capitalize}[1]{%
  \@ifpackagewith{inputenc}{utf8x}{\PrerenderUnicode{#1}}{}%
  \edef\@tempa{\expandafter\@gobble\string#1}%
  \edef\@tempb{\expandafter\@car\@tempa\@nil}%
  \edef\@tempa{\expandafter\@cdr\@tempa\@nil}%
  \uppercase\expandafter{\expandafter\def\expandafter\@tempb\expandafter{\@tempb}}%
  \@namedef{\@tempb\@tempa}{\expandafter\MakeUppercase\expandafter{#1}}}
\makeatother
```

so that `\PrerenderUnicode` is performed automatically when needed.

Comment: with you answer I get [this](http://f.cl.ly/items/2V2c182b0i042D130c1c/ss%202011-11-21_at_19.56.56.png)

Comment: @JuanPablo Please, edit your question to show the problem. Where do you get it?

Comment: What happens if I whant to use xelatex or lualatex. Can I use the PrerenderUnicode?

Comment: @TeXtnik You don't use `inputenc` with those engines to begin with.

Comment: Sorry @egreg, I was to edit the comment with more explanation. Using the first version of Capitalize does not output anything with XeLaTeX.

Comment: @TeXtnik I have no problem with `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newcommand{\facultad}{Ingeniería}
\newcommand{\Facultad}{\expandafter\MakeUppercase\expandafter{\facultad}}

\begin{document}
\Facultad
\end{document}`

Comment: You are right with your example, but `\Capitalize` does not output anything in my system.

Comment: @TeXtnik Of course, it doesn't make sense with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, with which you *mustn't* load `inputenc`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29720/discussion-between-textnik-and-egreg).

Answer (score 22):

You need to use `\MakeUppercase` instead of `\uppercase`. For information on the difference, see [Case-changing oddities](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-casechange) from the TeX FAQ.

For ligatures like `í`, you can either escape the character using `\'{i}`, or use it as-is with

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

in your document preamble. This should accommodate the use of ligatures in your input.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  \verb!\MakeUppercase{ingeniería}!: & \MakeUppercase{ingeniería} \\
  \verb!\MakeUppercase{ingenier\'{i}a}!: & \MakeUppercase{ingenier\'{i}a}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}​
```

Comment: I use quote,example `Ingeniería` and have problems with `MakeUppercase`

Comment: If you escape the ligature `í` as `\'i` and use `\MakeUppercase{Ingenier\'{i}a}` you obtain the correct result.

Comment: Just to nit-pick a bit: I don't think 〈í〉 can be considered a ligature, which would be a combination of two glyphs/[graphemes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature), e.g. 〈æ〉. 〈í〉 is simply an accented character/glyph/letter/grapheme.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, this article really helped:

https://texfaq.org/FAQ-casechange

I use:

```
\usepackage[overload]{textcase}
(...)
\newcommand{\iemph}[1]{\MakeTextUppercase{#1}}
(...)
\begin{document}
XXX \iemph{abc def ghi}
```

Comment: This works only for ASCII (basic latin) symbols.