# uppercase a \def

Tags: europecv

I'm working on an updated version of `europecv` that implements the graphical theme released in July 2013.

I solved all the problems I encountered, except for being able to make uppercase strings defined in the language files.

I tried to use `\uppercase`, `\MakeUppercase` and `\MakeTextUppercase` but without success.

I found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35680/uppercase-in-newcommand) question which seems like mine but the proposed solutions do not seem to work.

The class and all related files are hosted on github: https://github.com/leinardi/europecv2013

What I want to achive is to make uppercase [\ecv@infosectionkey](https://github.com/leinardi/europecv2013/blob/master/europecv2013.cls#L392).

Comment: `\MakeUppercase{\ecv@infosectionkey}` should work, if it doesn't can you not make a minimal example to post here that shows the problem and just defines the necessary macros inline and doesn't require fetching all the files from github

Comment: It might be an expansion problem?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I tried but does not work: I get a lot of "! Undefined control sequence." (full log http://pastebin.com/6WkZMCqv). I made a minimal example which can be downloaded here: https://db.tt/PLx48T43. To test simply uncomment the line 396 and comment the next line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The “error” is due to the fact that `\ecv@utf` is not defined as a robust command.

I would be very wary of changing a class file, but if you already do, it's time to modify also line 34, to read

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\ecv@utf[1]{{\inputencoding{utf8x}#1}}
```

instead of `\newcommand`. Then your modification

```
\textcolor{torea-bay}{\MakeUppercase{\ecv@infosectionkey}} & \LARGE\ecv@name\tabularnewline[10pt]
```

will work.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had lost all hope of solving the problem.

Comment: @RobertoLeinardi Sorry for being so late, but I didn't see the question until yesterday.