# How to get a version of \autoref that uppercases the first letter

Tags: hyperref, capitalization

So I'm using `hyperref` for all my referencing needs because it works very, very nicely. However, what I would like is to be able to choose whether the reference text is capitalised or not, so e.g.

```
see \autoref{fig:graph} for an example. \Autoref{fig:othergraph} shows the particular case
```

would produce

> see figure 3.4 for an example. Figure 3.5 shows the particular case

Now, the best way I can see for doing this is to let hyperref define `\autoref` as normal, and then define `\Autoref` by taking the text generated by `\autoref` and uppercasing the first letter thereof. But I cannot make this work!

Playing around with some code (and for now just trying to get any uppercasing at the level I want), I tried

```
\newcommand\foo[1]{foo #1}
\newcommand{\bar}[1]{\expandafter \MakeTextUppercase\expandafter{\foo{#1}}  }
```

for which `\foo{aaa} \bar{aaa}` produces

> foo aaa FOO AAA

as expected; I read this code as "first expand `\foo{#1}`, then apply uppercasing to the result". But with `\autoref`:

```
\newcommand{\Autoref}[1]{\expandafter\MakeTextUppercase\expandafter{\autoref{#1}} }
```

I get the error

> LaTeX Warning: Reference `LEM1' on page 1 undefined on input line 27.

Perhaps there are multiple levels of macro expansion going on here? But adding more `\expandafter`s doesn't seem to help, and moreover feels like a fairly blunt thing to do :P.

I also tried the `\Capitalise` macro from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35680/uppercase-in-newcommand) question, but it doesn't do anything at all to `\autoref`!

I think once I can get this working, making it only uppercase the first letter should be *relatively* trivial! But, does anyone have any advice here?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! With `cleveref` it's much easier.

Comment: @egreg Thanks, that's perfect! Could you please put that as an answer, and I'll accept :)